# What are clearcoat and ao masks? How do I use them?

Tags: masking

I have got some clearcoat and ao mask files for a 3d model. What are those and how do i use them?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it an AO mask, or is it an AO map?  The first would prevent calculated AO from affecting the model.  The second would create AO, for a shading environment that didn't calculate AO.  The only way to use an AO map or mask in Blender is with a Specular BSDF, usable only in Eevee.  It might be useful to see what you are doing with the material so far, and in which engine.

Comment: the first is an ao mask the other is a so called clearcoat mask. I am using cycles

Comment: Cycles doesn't have any AO, because it doesn't have ambient lighting, and use of any kind of AO map in it doesn't make sense.  Clearcoat mask, just plug into the coat/weight input for a Principled.  Although your clearcoat mask looks like it's probably more than one map, and the clearcoat mask is one channel (RGB) of the entire image.  Maybe red or blue.

Answer (score 1):

### For the AO texture:

As @Nathan already said, AO (ambient occlusion) is not really a thing in *Cycles* since there is no ambient lighting, however there is a node for it in the *Shader Editor* to calculate AO which you can use in *Cycles*.

AO is calculating how much ambient light reaches surfaces, which is usually less in areas that are close to something occluding them partially so the surface areas are darker there. Typically AO gives darker values in corners or inside a mesh or where two meshes meet etc.

While this is done in raytracing engines like *Cycles* automatically, people use the *Ambient Occlusion* node in materials for example to create darker parts on a mesh which - since they are more or less occluded - also can get darker through dust and dirt as it cumulates in those occluded parts.

Like in the example below, there is a simple blue material on the object. It has some sharper corners where the *Ambient Occlusion* node calculates a slight darkening. By the way, the *AO* output of the node always gives float values between 0 and 1. For darkening the corners, people often use a *Color Mix* node set to *Multiply* or *Darken* with their base color (of course it can be an image texture etc. as well) in the input *A* and the *AO* in the input *B*. However for this simple darkening the *Ambient Occlusion* node has its own *Color* setting and the *Color* output. If I choose my base color there (or plug something in there) and use the *Color* output of the node, the result is the same as multiplying in the *Mix Color* node.

[image: basic ambient occlusion]

A slightly different approach I use in the next example, I'm trying to make some kind of khaki/greyish dust in the corners which should not simply darken the color. *Mix Color* node leaves a lot of ways how to blend colors *A* and *B* together, in my case I just use *Mix* mode and make *A* the dust color and *B* the base color. The *AO* output I use as mix factor. Since the corners are darker in the *AO* values, they will show the first color and the rest shows the second, the base color.

[image: ao for dust]

Since I do not know the mesh of your model and how it should look like, it is up to you how to use the AO map. It looks definitely like being layed out for some UV map, so I would guess you have an image map for the base color which I would plug into *A* on a *Mix Color* node set to *Multiply* and the AO texture into *B*. Like this, only that you plug your color texture where my blue color is - and of course my object is not your mesh so the AO makes no sense:

[image: using the ao texture]

### For the Clearcoat texture:

What @Nathan said is mostly true, it seems that only one of the RGB channels is the clearcoat mask - but the others are probably no mask for anything. In this case it is the green channel which holds the mask information since it has a black (almost black with 0.004 or so) and white part, while the others are (apart from some JPG artifacts) completely white, so not really masking anything. This is the green channel, you can get it by plugging the texture into a *Separate Color* node and using the *G* output:

[image: clearcoat green channel]

The *Clearcoat* or just *Coat* setting in the current version of the *Principled BSDF* is used to simulate when an object with a rough surface (and therefore not sharp glossy reflections) which you want to preserve gets added a top coat of glossy varnish upon it - but not necessarily glossy, therefore the clearcoat has its own *Roughness* channel in the *Principled BSDF* shader.

And now it depends on you again to know what this could be useful for since I do not know your model. Generally you can use this green channel to determine where an object should have a clearcoat layer (where it is white or 1) and where not (black or 0). Or this texture was made for a different working shader, and you need to invert the color to switch white and black and so the clearcoat/no clearcoat distribution.

To do this the usual way, leave the coat roughness at the default low value and plug the green channel (or the inverted version) into the *Weight* input under *Coat* in the *Principled BSDF* to mask where the clearcoat is:

[image: clearcoat comparison]

You could also set the *Weight* to 1 to have a clearcoat overall, and then plug the green channel into the *Roughness* input in the *Coat* section. Although with black and white resulting in black being completely smooth and glossy and white being completely rough and not glossy at all, it will visually mostly appear as the example before with the *Weight* just being inverted.